# How to replace a hash pattern inside file and directory names (Linux)

Tags: regex, linux, shell, pattern-matching

I've just backed up the notes I have in [Notion](https://www.notion.so/), and they use hashcodes in the notes names to make them unique apparently.

For example, this is might be a note-folder with some notes:

```
Archive e74f698cb73b42c790d08999bdbe47e4
├── Note 1 cda63bef095a493f9847d516cf34fa5f.md
├── Note 2 dda63bef095a493f9847d516cf34fa5f.md
```

(Sometimes there's also a `.csv` file for tables)

I was trying to use a regex like `[a-z0-9]{32}` to replace the pattern, but was having difficulty making it work with `s/`:

```sh
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/[a-z0-9]{32}//g'
```

(I'm not sure I really understand what the purpose of `-print0` and `-0` is.)

The code above only works for files, but I've also tried to use something like `mv $f ${f:0:-34}` though I couldn't make it work either. Is there a way of making this replacing with only one line for both files and folders, without `for`s?

I've tried many other answers on StackOverflow about this but almost all I've found so far either only deal with files or with fixed words as patterns.

I wanted to use the Mass-Move command line tool (`mmv`), but there's no official distribution for Arch Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[steeldriver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4440445/steeldriver) has created [a very complete and thorough answer on the Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/640612/364698). The whole discussion was originally supposed to be all here. But the question was at some point closed and I had to reask it there. When it came back up here I gave [steeldriver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4440445/steeldriver) a heads up, but he isn't apparently either interested or aware. I'll leave this answer until he chooses to copy-paste or link his own content here.

Sorry for the unexpected cross-/copy-paste-posting.